# SAME DIGIT NUMBER PUZZLE

Tags: combinatorics, formation-of-numbers

You have 5 numbers

> 1, 9, 3, 5, and 7

you need to arrange these number like

> **Rules** 
>  create 2 pairs from numbers above keep one of the number in the middle then apply this law 
>  `1st pair * last pair - middle number`.
>   after arranging and  applying the above rules the result should be a number where whose all digits are same.

example if I arrange it like below

> 79(1st-pair)  5(middle)  31(2nd-pair) 
>   79 * 31 - 5 = 2444  (1st pair * last pair - middle number)

it should be 4444 instead of 2444 ( it can be a right solution if instead of 2444 I get 4444)

Comment: Do we have to list all solutions, or at least one? (I don't know if there are multiple, but I found one)

Comment: @someone I think there is just 1 solution the other is mirror :) let's see if you come up with more

Comment: is it pair * pair - digit or pair * digit - pair? the rules says the first, but the example demonstrates the second

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only solutions are

> 39, 1, 57 ($39\cdot 57 - 1 = 2222$)
>  and 57, 1, 39 ($57\cdot 39 - 1 = 2222$ too, because it's pretty much the same)

After finding these, I have brute forced this with the following ugly Mathematica script to prove no other solutions exist:

> `Print@Select[Permutations[{1,3,5,7,9}],Equal@@IntegerDigits[(#[[1]]*10+#[[2]])*(#[[4]]*10+#[[5]])-#[[3]]]&]`

Answer (score 5):

I have found one answer

> $(39 \times 57) - 1 = 2222$